# Flask NameError: name 'user' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, session, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I have a Flask app: 
[image]

The user dashboard showing after the user is logging in, and then clicking on the search link in the navigation pane, a search page should come up. When I am clicking on "Search", I get a "NameError: name 'user' is not defined".

**Traceback:**

```
NameError
NameError: name 'user' is not defined

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\Users\fbagi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Users\fbagi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\fbagi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\fbagi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\fbagi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\fbagi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\fbagi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\fbagi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\fbagi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\fbagi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "C:\Users\fbagi\Documents\GitHub\[edited]\search\views.py", line 32, in search
return render_template('search.html', user=user)
NameError: name 'user' is not defined
The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application. You can now look at the traceback which led to the error.
To switch between the interactive traceback and the plaintext one, you can click on the "Traceback" headline. From the text traceback you can also create a paste of it. For code execution mouse-over the frame you want to debug and click on the console icon on the right side.

 You can execute arbitrary Python code in the stack frames and there are some extra helpers available for introspection:

dump() shows all variables in the frame
dump(obj) dumps all that's known about the object
```

**search.html:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %} 

{% block title %}{{ user.username }} - Profile{% endblock %} 

{% block header %}<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/base.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">{% endblock %}

{% block content %} 

{% include "navbar.html" %}

<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-3">
<body>

<form action="{{url_for('search_app.search')}}" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="SearchForm">
<p>        <input type="submit" name="my-form" value="Send"></p>
</form>
{{ results }}
</body>

{% endblock %}
```

**search/views.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, jsonify, url_for, redirect, request
import operator
from search.forms import SearchForm
from user.models import User

search_app = Blueprint('search_app', __name__)
@search_app.route('/search', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
    form = SearchForm()
    return render_template('search.html', user=user)
```

I tried defining *user* variable by including into **views.py**:

```
user = User.objects.filter(username=session.get('username')).first()
```

...but still getting the same issue.

When I am exporting the User object in run-time,everything checks out:

```
 >>> from user.models import User
 >>> User
 <class 'user.models.User'>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You  need to pass a valid instance of `User` class. Something like this -

```
def search():
    form = SearchForm()
    user = User.objects.filter(username=session.get('username')).first()
    return render_template('search.html', user=user)
```

For authentication using flask, you can refer below links

- [flask-login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [flask-login-example](https://github.com/rohitchormale/flask-examples/blob/master/flask-login-example.py)